# How to Delete data from 2 tables using JOIN in SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, join, subquery, android-sqlite

I have the below tables

[image: Tables Structure]

I want to delete the data corresponding to the **productId** from both the tables. I have studied that JOIN can not be applied with DELETE in sqlite so i have tried the below query

```
DELETE FROM optionToValues WHERE optionToValues.optionId   IN
(SELECT optionToValues.optionId
FROM optionToValues 
JOIN productOptions on productOptions.optionId = optionToValues.optionId 
WHERE productOptions.product_id = 82)
```

But no delete operation is performed. Please suggest me something how we can achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That query doesn't really make sense. You're looking for product_id within a set of optionIds. Maybe you just want `DELETE FROM productOptions WHERE product_id = 82`? If not, what exactly ARE you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Or are you trying to delete all the options for a certain product?

Comment: @323go i have to delete the productoptions and then that product also

Comment: "Delete data from 2 tables" isn't possible with a single statement. You can sort of accomplish this with foreign key actions (for example, to `RESTRICT` deletion where you'd get invalid relations, or `CASCADE` the deletion across tables): http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want this --

```
DELETE 
  FROM optionToValues
 WHERE optionId IN ( SELECT optionId FROM productOptions WHERE product_id = 82 )
```

and

```
DELETE
  FROM productOptions
 WHERE product_id = 82
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `optionToValues.optionid` should be a foreign key to `productOptions.optionID` using `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  With that in place, when you delete an entry from `productOptions`, it's corresponding entries in `optionToValues` will be deleted for you.

Alternatively, you could define a trigger on `productOptions` which would delete the `optionToValues` rows.